# \n not working in UIlabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, newline, uilabel

I've seen similar questions here, but still can figure out why it's not working.

How to add line break (in other words add new paragraph) in multiline UIlabel?

I have a label with a lot of text,

```
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.sizeToFit;
```

but I'm still getting something like this:
"Some text here\nAnd here I want new line"

Thank you

Comment: how do you set the text on the label? I had this problem once because the real string was @"some text\\nmore text".

Comment: No, I don't use escape in original string, I have single backslash

Comment: AngeDeLaMort was correct. IB text auto-escapes the \ char. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UILabel won't respect \n, You can use option-return (in Interface builder) to force where you want a line break.

You can use a UIWebView in place of the label and then you can format however you like.
(And set the lineBreakMode as AngeDeLaMort says above.)

Comment: And don't forget to put the number of line to 0 !

Comment: This is incorrect! UILabel will respect \n, but it won't respect \\n (for good reason!) :)

Comment: Using UIWebview for UILabel is like slingshot over shotgun. Better check with `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` attributes. \n will break line and put content on next screen. Also check with your label height, if you don't have enough space, this second line will get trimmed off.

Answer (score 20):

This is an old question, but just wanted to let you know that `\r` works like a charm :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this One :

```
lbl.text = @"My \n label";
lbl.numberofLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Your issue may be different... but mine was a literal character `\n`, which is actually `\\n` in memory.

I solved it with:

```
label.text = [rawText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

You still need to set line break mode as well as numberOfLines for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

actually there is a way to do that. try

```
    unichar chr[1] = {'\n'};
NSString *singleCR = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chr length:1];
    [yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"new%@line",singleCR]];
```

Answer (score 2):

If your string is really ok, maybe you can try adding this line as well:

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: for me, `lbl.numberOfLines = 2;` `lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;` worked.

Answer (score 2):

use **ctrl + Enter** in storyboard, and make **number of lines** as 0

Answer (score 1):

This is old question but if any one want to do from interface builder.then  it is easy and simple

select label and change type to **attributed** by default it is **plain**

[image]

now wherever you want to **\n** there just use `Alt + Enter` and you will get new line

hope it is helpful to someone who is using interface builder to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question, but i was wondering - could the problem be `lbl.sizeToFit;` ?

if you could set frame like CGRectMake(0,0,300,300) -  does that solves the problem? Because `\n`  works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet;
NSString *formatted = [[unformatted componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

UILabel use \n to made new line. \n need a space in the back.

Comment: A space is **not** needed in the back.

Comment: It's more helpful if you show an example when you answer a question. Thanks!