# label Line Feed

Tags: objective-c

I would like to write two lines in my iphone label, what I read I should do is:

```
NSString *received = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Rocio\n,%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];  

self.label.text = received;
```

So, the "\n" is the LF.

Why is not it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default label can display only 1 line of text. Use `setNumberOfLines:` method to set the number of lines you need.

Answer (score 1):

i add:

```
self.label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
self.label.setNumberOfLines=0;
```

and [look it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417103/n-not-working-in-uilabel)